# Handy dates conversion

Tags: functions, string-manipulation, date-and-time

I feel like something very basic is missing me,

```
$dateformat = {"Year", "Month", "Day", "Hour"};

date = DateString[$dateformat]

DateString["Date"]
```

> ```
> "2015051215"
> "Tuesday 12 May 2015"
> ```

**How to get what `DateString["Date"]` gives using `$dateformat` and `date`?**

According to the last example in documentation I thought this should work:

```
DateString[{date, $dateformat},"Date"]
```

> DateString::str: String 2015051215 cannot be interpreted as a date in format {Year,Month,Day,Hour}. >>

but it isn't..

Comment: My initial thoughts are that it's a bug. The documentation leads you to think this will work: `DateList[{"1505", {"YearShort", "Month"}}]`. However, you need a character like "/" between the YearShort and Month.

Comment: @MichaelHale Yep, `DateString[{StringInsert[date, "/", {3, 5, 7}], $dateformat}, "Date"]` does not look nice.

Comment: Based on the behavior of `DateList[{"1505", {"YearShort"}}]` I think YearShort automatically switches to Year if it finds more than two numeric characters in a row. So then it's complaining that it doesn't find a Month.

Comment: @MichaelHale Great. I don't feel like writing another report, I haven't got any answer for last three...

Comment: Technically, they could argue it's a minor doc issue. MonthShort specifically states it looks for a 1 or 2 digit month. So perhaps they forgot to mention that YearShort looks for a 2 or 4 digit year. It currently just says 2 digit year.

Comment: I sent feedback.

Comment: @MichaelHale Thanks. p.s. I'm not using YearShort in this example so this does not matter.

Comment: @MichaelHale any answer?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I was on a camping/canoeing trip. Yes, the responder agreed the documentation could be improved and forwarded it to the development team.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a simple fix/workaround.  It appears that all you need to do to make your code work as intended is to make the following change to your `$dateFormat` assignment:

```
$dateFormat = {"Year", "", "Month", "", "Day", "", "Hour"}
```

This generates an identical string to your test example, but it appears that the empty strings are necessary to correctly parse the resulting text.

Using this modified date format,

```
DateString[{"2015051210", $dateFormat}, "Date"]
```

returns

```
"Tuesday 12 May 2015"
```

as desired.

Comment: Good idea, I'm surprised it works ;) p.s. you can use `Riffle`, it will be more compact.

Comment: @Kuba  Yes I was a little surprised myself.  Definitely curious behaviour, but perhaps you have to make it explicit that there are no delimiters in the string.  I agree that `Riffle` makes things more compact (and robust).